# New to Ruby, my program returns the error "String can't be coerced to fixnum"

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to make 3 simple programs, I've already done them in Python, and C++ which I'm experienced with. Ruby, however, is very new to me.
Here's my code, can anyone tell me why I'm getting the error message "String can't be coerced to fixnum"

```
c=1
a=0
print("Please Enter Your Name: ")
name=gets.chomp
print("Please Enter the Last Digit of Your Student Number: ")
b= gets
l=name.length
while a<l do
    if ((c%b)==0) 
        print name[a]
    else
        puts name[a]
    end
c+=1
a+=1
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulo operator (`%`) can't be applied to a number on the left side and a string on the right side. You need to convert `b` an integer before applying modulo with [`to_i`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-to_i) ("to integer"):

```
if c % b.to_i == 0
  print name[a]
else
```

I also removed the unnecessary parenthesis.

Comment: That has fixed it perfectly, thank you. I didn't realize that the input was a string!

Answer (score 1):

you need to explicitly cast your variable b from gets to integer

```
while a<l do
    if ((c%b.to_i)==0) 
        print name[a]
    else
        puts name[a]
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is at the line:

```
if ((c%b)==0)
```

If so, the reason is that you have `b = gets`. And since `gets is actually a string, you are trying to do something like`5%'3'` which is not valid.

You should instead make `b = gets.chomp` and then use `b.to_i`, like so:

```
c=1
a=0
print("Please Enter Your Name: ")
name=gets.chomp
print("Please Enter the Last Digit of Your Student Number: ")
b= gets.chomp
l=name.length
while a<l do
    if ((c%b.to_i)==0) 
        print name[a]
    else
        puts name[a]
    end
c+=1
a+=1
end
```